# devise multiple models application helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, helper

I have problems with devise :

In my ApplicationHelper i already have

```
def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

and it works.

I just add a "worker" model. How to set in my Applicationhelper the 3 def for users OR workers. I would not prefer to set 3 other def and rename all my devise "workers" views.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by checking the parent class using the helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name

    if self.class.parent == Workers
      :worker
    else 
      :user
    end 
  end

  def resource
    if self.class.parent == Workers
        @resource ||= Worker.new
    else 
        @resource ||= User.new
    end 
  end

  def devise_mapping
    if self.class.parent == Workers
      @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:worker]
    else 
      @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
    end 
  end
end
```